# Instead of bullets,is it possible to get image before string in android

Tags: android

I have an string value before string i like to get my image as bullets?how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_bullet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/bullet"/>   

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:text="This is TextView"/>
```